# How to configure WebLogic Server to existing Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, weblogic

I just installed WebLogic Server. But in install process I forgot about setting path to my Eclipse and now I work with new installed Eclipse (from oracle installation wizard).
How to configure Oracle WebLogic Server to use my Eclipse?

P.S. I will not want to lose my settings and plugins, futhermore - I will not want to install all my plugins and configurate eclipse again.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use your old Eclipse installation integrated with WebLogic Server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open your old Eclipse installation, click Window->Show View->Other...
Type `servers`, select Servers and click OK.
Right-click the Servers view, click New->Server

Now, it depends on which version of Eclipse you are using, but you should be able to either:
1)Expand the Oracle folder and select your version of WebLogic Server or;
2)Click "download additional server adapters" and download WebLogic adapters from Oracle

Now just follow the wizard (point the path to your WebLogic installation, JVM path, etc) and you should be ready to go.