# How to design the directory structure to develop EJB applications

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I have installed weblogic server in my system.Now,i want to learn to develop EJB applications.But,i have heard that a special kind of directory structure is required to keep .java files and .jar files in the application directory (if not developing using eclipse) .So,i need information regarding the directory structure and then how to deploy the application on weblogic server.

Comment: This is a hugely broad question and can't be answered in a single SO posting. You need to read plenty of tutorials to get things going.

Comment: @Kayaman can u suggest me a link from where i should proceed.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time at Google first. You can't just ask others for help in every single thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an IDE with JAVA EE support for this.Here it is a list: IntellJ IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans, STS, JDeveloper, Etc.

Comment: First i was trying to use it with eclipse,but some problem is occuring with that.Can u guide me through the process of configuring weblogic with eclipse if u have done this ?

Comment: Here you have another question (with answer) that can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246223/how-to-configure-weblogic-server-to-existing-eclipse

Comment: @  Elvermg  But the problem is that it i already followed that way but it's not getting configured properly.I am asking u if u have done this thing then u may help me.

Comment: a874 you can follow the link from @SkyWalker.It is short and clear.